# Keep div after showing with a dropdown and on button submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code below will show the div with the text field username after you select the drop down Yes but it will hide div if you click submit, i want it to still show the div after you click submit thank.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
window.onload=function(){
document.getElementById('user').addEventListener('change', function () {
    var style = this.value == 1 ? 'block' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('hidden_div').style.display = style;
});
}
</script>

<form method="post" action="">
Are You Ready:<br>
    <select id="user" name="form_select">
       <option value="0">No</option>
       <option value="1">Yes</option>
    </select>

<div id="hidden_div" style="display: none;">
    Username: <br>
    <input type="text" name="username"><br>
</div>

<br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The submit forces the page to refresh.

You can add an event listener to the submit, and prevent the default behavior.

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e = e || event;

  e.preventDefault();

  // Do Something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#user").change(function() {
        var style = $(this).val() == 1 ? 'block' : 'none';
        $("#hidden_div").css("display", style);
    });
    
    $('form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  Are You Ready:<br>
  <select id="user" name="form_select">
      <option value="0">No</option>
      <option value="1">Yes</option>
  </select>

  <div id="hidden_div" style="display: none;">
      Username: <br>
      <input type="text" name="username"><br>
  </div>
  <br>
  
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```